# pip path: anaconda vs. native python (on macOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pip

I am using macOS X and I installed native Python 3.8 in April, and the packages of this version are stored in:

```
/Users/hubert/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/
```

Some weeks later, in May, I installed Anaconda, but it uses a different path for it's packages:

```
/Users/hubert/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Today I needed to install a new package to be used in a native Python script. I typed:

```
pip install ffmpeg
```

I've got a success-message. But when I wanted to run my script, it couldn't find ffmpeg. I rebooted my Mac, but the script still couldn't find it. So I again tried `pip install ffmpeg`. Now I did get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4)
```

But obviously native Pythons wants to have it in the other path.

My questions:

1. Is it save to just copy the directories `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-1.4.dist-info` from the anaconda directory to the native directory?
2. How can I tell *pip* to use the native Python directory to install new packages?
3. Is it a good idea to merge the two site-packages directories? And if it's a good idea: What is the best way to let native Python 3.8 and Anaconda (which obviously uses Python 3.7) use the same site-packages directory?

Comment: Maybe [Conda & Dealing with Conflicting Python(s) in your system](https://dev.to/bgalvao/conda--dealing-with-conflicting-pythons-in-your-system-62n) or [how to update system python instead of anaconda site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+update+system+python+instead+of+anaconda+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk006s4wqoNO9CLxXCoUFV7NaD3iNMA:1593188118573&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEq_ie8J_qAhUYIDQIHSwcA1QQrQIoBDAAegQIAxAN&biw=1920&bih=975)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is it a good idea to modify site-packages manually?

Probably not. The problems you're having are the sorts of problems that virtual environment managers like Anaconda were created to avoid. If you start messing with site-packages, at a minimum you run the risk of creating a lot of new problems in your dependency tree. Unless you need to use two different python installations in the same shell prompt at the same time, your life will be much easier if you just use Anaconda to manage all your environments.

(Bear in mind that creating a new installation of Python 3.8 with `ffmpeg` installed is as easy as `conda create -n mynewenv python=3.8 ffmpeg`. Then run `conda activate mynewenv` whenever you want to use Python 3.8 with `ffmpeg` installed.)

## How to install packages in the right place with pip

### Use the right copy of pip

The easiest way is to make sure that you're using the right `pip`. On MacOS or Linux, you can do this by running `which python` or `which pip` before you start installing things. If you want to install to native Python, you'll probably have to run `conda deactivate` before you start running `pip` commands.

It's always possible that the `pip` in your search path is actually a symlink, so it's worth checking this with `file -h $(which pip)`. (In my case, I have a couple of versions of Python installed with homebrew, which likes to symlink things into `/usr/local/bin`.)

#### Example

```sh
(base) ~ $ which python
/miniconda3/bin/python
(base) ~ $ which pip
/miniconda3/bin/pip
(base) ~ $ conda deactivate
~ $ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
~ $ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
~ $ file -h $(which pip)
/usr/local/bin/pip: symbolic link to ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/bin/pip
```

Note that the `pip` for your native installation of Python 3.8 is probably called `pip3`.

### Check where pip is sending stuff

You can check to see where `pip`/`pip3` is installing stuff by checking where a specific package was installed. This can be a way to double-check where things will be installed if it isn't obvious from `which pip`.

#### Example

```sh
~ $ pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
...
wheel                         0.33.4
~ $ pip show wheel
Name: wheel
Version: 0.33.4
Summary: A built-package format for Python.
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/wheel
Author: Daniel Holth
Author-email: dholth@fastmail.fm
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Note the `Location` line.